# similar function refactoring pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have about 20 functions with almost the same pattern, i run on array of Sites, create SiteOperation with Site object and perform some operation ( in this case with one param but sometimes there are none or more)

```
int wantedBandwidthInLBps = 2048 / 8;
foreach (Sites site in _sitesManagement.GetAll())
{
 SiteOperation siteOperation = new SiteOperation(site);
 siteOperation.LimitBandwidth(wantedBandwidthInLBps);
}

foreach (Sites site in _sitesManagement.GetAll())
{
 SiteOperation siteOperation = new SiteOperation(site);
 siteOperation.KillJames();
}

foreach (Sites site in _sitesManagement.GetAll())
{
 SiteOperation siteOperation = new SiteOperation(site);
 siteOperation.FlyToMoon(2012, new TaskIdentifier(10,20));
}
```

Is it possible to wrap this code, so i will just send action to lets say _sitesManagement which will run this action on all Sites ?

Comment: can you post a few of the other functions so we can see exactly what could be wrapped up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
void PerformOperationOnAllSites(Action<SiteOperation> doIt) {
    foreach (Sites site in _sitesManagement.GetAll()) {
        SiteOperation siteOperation = new SiteOperation(site);
        doIt(siteOperation);
    }
}

...

_sitesManagement.PerformOperationOnAllSites(op => op.LimitBandwidth(wantedBandwidthInLBps));
_sitesManagement.PerformOperationOnAllSites(op => op.KillJames());
_sitesManagement.PerformOperationOnAllSites(op => op.FlyToMoon(2012, new TaskIdentifier(10,20));
```

Comment: Am I wrong saying that this method will require me to get SiteOperation as param to each method i have ?

Comment: @eugeneK This method will pass `SiteOperation` back to your *lambdas* as the only parameter, so your lambdas will need to operate on it, perhaps along with some other data available in the context of the call (such as `wantedBandwidthInLBps` in the first call).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void DoSiteOperationActions(Action<SiteOperation> toDo)
{
        foreach (Sites site in _sitesManagement.GetAll())
        {
           SiteOperation mySiteOperation = new SiteOperation(site);
           toDo(mySiteOperation);
        }
}
```

and then you can call it like...

`DoSiteOperationActions(so => so.FlyToMoon(2012, new TaskIdentifier(10,20)));`

The syntax might be a little off, I have no IDE here, but more info here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good candidate for the Template method pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static void InvokeMethod(Action<SiteOperation> action)
    {
        foreach (SiteOperation siteOperation in _sitesManagement.GetAll()
                               .Select(site=>new SiteOperation(site))
        {
            action(siteOperation);
        }
    }
..

    public static void KillJames()
    {
        InvokeMethod(so => so.KillJames());
    }

    public static void LimitBandwidth(int wantedBandwidthInLBps)
    {
        InvokeMethod(so => so.LimitBandwidth(wantedBandwidthInLBps));
    }

    public static void FlyToMoon(int year=2012, TaskIdentifier ti=new TaskIdentifier(10,20))
    {
        InvokeMethod(so => so.FlyToMoon(year, ti));
    }
```